# Extracting a subset of JSON key-value pairs as an Object from a Parent JSON Object in dataweave 2.0 Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

I have a dataweave challenge which I couldn't figure out without making it complicated.

**Input JSON payload**

```
{
   "Name"     : "Mr.wolf",
   "Age"      : 26,
   "Region"   : "USA",
   "SubRegion": "Pacific"
}
```

**Output needed**

```
{
   "Name"     : "Mr.wolf",
   "Age"      : 26
}
```

Here is a catch. I am not allowed to use the above shown output format structure in the transform message, or either remove the keys using "-" operation.

So basically, we shouldn't use the below dwl.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload - "Region" - "SubRegion")
```

or

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
   "Name"     : payload.Name,
   "Age"      : payload.Age
}
```

How can we achieve the required output by using Lambdas, Reduce, mapObject, functions or any other operation of choice, other than the restricted methods/usage shown above.

Any solution provided is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you after @Thinker-101?  Do you want to remove fields without hardconding them?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am looking after. Thanks to Salim Khan. I got the answer.

Comment: You can just try this: `payload -- ["Region","SubRegion"]` -- where the array of strings is setup dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filterObject ((value, key,index) -> (index <2 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `filterObject` could work for you. [Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filterobject)

```
payload filterObject ((value, key) -> (key ~= "Name" or key ~= "Age"))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is good. Is there any way we could pass a numeric value as a function argument which can extract the required JSON ? The reason I have excluded the other 2 methods is to fulfill the intention of not Hardcoding any key names in the dwl. This approach would complicate things when we have more number of keys to extract. If the input has 30 key value pair and if we want to extract the first 10 keys alone. There must be some other approach to this.

Comment: I tried constucting a function without using any hardcoded key names, but it threw me a `Max stack 256 bytes. Stackoverflow.` error in an online dataweave editor.

Comment: Can you post your function you came up with? If you use index instead of key in the `filterObject` function you can extract the first 10 items. I.e. `payload filterObject ((value, key, index) -> (index < 10))`

Answer (score 1):

Another rendition of the same approach.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject {
    (($$) : $) if (($$) ~= "Name" or ($$) ~= "Age")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this approach will create too much boiler plate code if the input has more number of keys to extract. Can we implement a function which can take a number and extract those many key values without Hardcoding the keys in dwl.

Comment: Boilerplate - How so? what's the context for that?

Answer (score 0):

The other rendition being:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload mapObject {
    (($$) : $) if (($$$) < 2)
}
```